# multiple upload laravel with the same name

Tags: php, laravel

I've created new code for editor to upload image by laravel.
I use a laravel method with a loop, so if I selecetd 2 images it's upload the first one twice.

How can I solve it?

I think I need to clear Input :)

```php
public function ajax_editor_image() {
    if (Input::file()) {
        $image = Input::file('image');
        $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $path = public_path('uploads/' . $filename);
        // Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(200, 200)->save($path);
        Input::file('image')->move('uploads/', $filename);
        $base_url = URL::to('/');;
        return response()->json([
            'data' => [
                "id"          => "",
                "title"       => null,
                "description" => null,
                "datetime"    => 1462962209,
                "type"        => "image/jpeg",
                "animated"    => false,
                "width"       => 720,
                "height"      => 960,
                "size"        => 108627,
                "views"       => 0,
                "bandwidth"   => 0,
                "vote"        => null,
                "favorite"    => false,
                "nsfw"        => null,
                "section"     => null,
                "account_url" => null,
                "account_id"  => 0,
                "in_gallery"  => false,
                "deletehash"  => "NYoWYJZkpdFyahb",
                "name"        => "",
                "link"        => $base_url . '/uploads/' . $filename,
                "success"     => true,
                "status"      => 200
            ]
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this name as image name

```
$filename  = time() .'-'.$image->getClientOriginalName().'.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

I also had the same problem . sometimes it will upload at same time and your file name would be same. so by adding name to the image also it would be definitely unique.

I think it will help.

Comment: Glad to help @AhmedNaguib :). This is a generic problem and accept and up vote this answer so that it would be helpful for others